# Is it possible to use includes and replace method on multiple strings at the same time?

Tags: javascript, api, replace, include

I'm retrieving data via an api on football. There are some mistakes written in the data that needs to be adjusted. What I wanna know is, if it is possible to write a single piece of code that does the job instead of repeating an if/else statement multiple times as shown below.
Thank you.

```
// So replace the strings in the includes methods in one execution 

if( el.team.name.includes("Rotterdam")){
      el.team.name = el.team.name.replace("Rotterdam", "");
    }

    if(el.team.name.includes("'65")){
      el.team.name = el.team.name.replace("'65", "");
    }  

    if(el.team.name.includes("Almelo")){
      el.team.name = el.team.name.replace("Almelo", "");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate between all possible strings you want to remove with a regular expression, then perform a global replacement with the empty string:

```
el.team.name = el.team.name.replace(/Rotterdam|65|Alemo/g, '');
```

---

Side note - even with your original code, there's no need to test whether the substring is included first. If `.replace` finds no matches, nothing will be replaced, so the following code would work too (though the regex is preferable):

```
el.team.name = el.team.name.replace("Rotterdam", "");
el.team.name = el.team.name.replace("'65", "");
el.team.name = el.team.name.replace("Almelo", "");
```

as would calling `.replace` on the result of the last `.replace`:

```
el.team.name = el.team.name
  .replace("Rotterdam", "")
  .replace("'65", "")
  .replace("Almelo", "");
```

(the above can be a good strategy when a single regular expression would be too hard to read, or when you have different strings to insert when a match is found)

Comment: Thanks very much CertainPerformance! I'll guess I choose the latter option. Although the regexp looks very neat since it is the shortest way the reach your goal. Good to know that you don't even need the includes method here. Great.